# Django URL's not working

Tags: python, django

My Django URLs.py isn't working it returns a 404.

**forums/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.forums, name='forums'),
    url('topics/<int:id>/', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('announcements.urls')),
    path('faq/', include('FAQ.urls')),
    path('', include('account.urls')),
    path('forum/', include('forums.urls')),
]
```

I am trying to go to the URL /forum/topics/4

Comment: Did you included 'forums' in installed apps ( Django's settings.py) ?

Comment: I did, yeah.
15characters

Comment: The url you are navigating to needs a trailing slash `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up path() and url().

In your main urls.py you use path() for the URL patterns. But in your app urls you use url(), but use the path style - `/<int:id>/` - instead of the url style (regex).

The easiest fix is just to change to path() throughout - if you do this you also need to change the first path to just `''`.